# Modifying an ArrayBuffer with index access

Tags: javascript

I create an array of 3 bytes : `array_A`

I modify it : `array_A[0]=34`

I create a 8-byte buffer with a `Uint8array` view referring to `array_A`:

```js
let typedarray = new Uint8Array(a);
```

why such a result with `console.log` ?

```js
{  
  "0": 0, // where is 34 ?  
  "1": 0,  
  "2": 0  
}
```

```js
let array_A=new ArrayBuffer(3);
array_A[0]=34;
console.log(array_A);
let typedarray = new Uint8Array(array_A);
console.log(typedarray);
```

Comment: You [can't directly manipulate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) the contents of an `ArrayBuffer`. Doing `array_A[0] = 34` is the same as doing `array_A["foo"] = 34`, you're setting an arbitrary property on the object, but you're not modifying the contents of the buffer. See [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) for more information on how to use buffers correctly.